# A product of two sums of four squares

Tags: number-theory, analysis, elementary-number-theory

I am dealing with a problem and I hope you can help  me. I have already proved this:

Let us suppose that integers $m$ and $n$ can be written as sum of squares of two integers. Prove that m*n can also be written as sum of squares of two integers.

Now I am trying to prove this: Let us suppose that integers $m$ and $n$ can be written as the sum of squares of four integers, i.e., $m=m_1^2+m_2^2+m_3^2+m_4^2$ and $n=n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2+n_4^2$. Prove that $mn$ can also be written as sum of squares of four integers.

Can you help me on this? 
Thank You for reading my post.

Comment: Please make titles more informative.

Answer (score 6):

Please see [Euler's four squares identity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity)

It is analogous to the identity that you probably used to prove the result about the product of two sums of two squares. That identity can be interpreted as a result about the norm of the product of two **complex numbers**.

And it turns out that the four-squares identity can be interpreted as a result about the norm of a product of two **quaternions**. But Euler did not know that, since quaternions were only discovered many years later.

Comment: lol of course Euler solved this one already :-P

Comment: But he did not manage to show that every non-negative integer is a sum of four squares. Lagrange did that.

Comment: ah icic... well I guess it's good to know that there were still some things left that Euler didn't prove...

Answer (score 2):

Just like the sum of two squares is related to the norm (square of the absolute value) of the complex numbers, or more precisely [the Gaussian integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), so the sum of four squares is related to the norm of quaternions, or more precisely [the Hurwitz integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem#Proof_using_the_Hurwitz_integers).